# Can a bride's father call off a wedding?

Tags: halacha, marriage, secular-culture

Both in the Torah and various halachick literature, it often appears as though a woman's father has a large role in deciding who she marries. One example is in Shemiras Halashon, it says that if the groom-to-be is not fit, to tell the bride's father even if that means it will cancel the wedding. Or in the Torah, there are references to a father giving his daughter to his servent as a wife, or (though not a halachic decider) Leah was given to Yaakov first as per her father's desire.

So my question is, can a father prohibit his daughter from marrying somebody, or were those things simply non-halachick byproducts of cultural practices that we don't have anymore?